# Convincing reason to define subschemes using immersions and not monomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

In category theory there is a general and very simple notion of subobject: a subobject of $X$ is a class of monomorphisms $A\to X$, where we identify $A\to X$ and $B\to X$ when they are related by an isomorphism $A\to B$. This is quite easy to use and understand, and works very well in a lot of categories.

But this is not what we do when we define subschemes: instead of using all monomorphisms, we use a somewhat ad hoc subclass of monomorphisms, namely immersions. Immersions are defined using two base cases, open immersions and closed immersions, which have a quite different flavor and behavior (not at all like in topology where open/closed subspaces can be easily defined in terms of each other).

There are historical reasons for this choice, and, of course, it works, but it has always bugged me on some level. Could someone give a clear and convincing mathematical argument for defining subschemes with immersions and not general monomorphisms? What I am looking for is something that would become true with this more general definition and makes you think "Oh yeah, we *clearly* don't want that to be true for what we call a subscheme." (Or of course equivalently something that becomes false and makes you think "We clearly wanted that to be true for subschemes".)

For instance, things like "a subscheme would not always be locally closed on a topological level" would not do it for me, since... so what? Subspaces in topology are not locally closed in general and no one is complaining.

Comment: In categories of geometric objects there are often "too many" monomorphisms. For instance, in the category of topological spaces, a continuous map is a monomorphism as soon as it is injective on points – so you end up with more than just subspaces. The same kind of thing happens in the category of smooth manifolds.  Do you really want to think of, say, the half-open interval $[0, 2 \pi)$ as being a subobject of the circle $S^1$ that contains all the points but yet is not the whole circle? (cont.)

Comment: In the category of schemes things are even more complicated because we _do_ want to have things like $\operatorname{Spec} k$ as a subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec} k [x] / (x^2)$ but not $\mathbb{A}^1_k \amalg \mathbb{A}^0_k$ as a subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, etc.

Comment: @ZhenLin So maybe a simpler version of the question is: what's wrong with the idea of using *regular* monomorphisms to define subschemes?

Comment: I'm not sure if immersions of schemes are regular monomorphisms in general. Regular monomorphisms don't always behave well, anyway, and are sensitive to what quotients you have in your category. For instance, in the category of Hausdorff spaces, only closed embeddings are regular monomorphisms.